# Capturing Audio buffer in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-audio

Hello All
In my application , i need to enable voice communication over IP,i.e. need to capture the Audio buffer and send it over the Internet, through secure socket, 
In the Lower layer everything is ready, I need the entry point to start Voice Communication, but not getting any pointer in the Apple documentation, so far i have done following,

1 -- In the Apple documentation going through CoreAudio programming guide, is this right place to start,

2 -- if yes, somewhere it says, i need to download CoreAudio SDK, will it not come along with standard XCOde and Cocoa framework,

Kind Regards
Rohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: CoreAudio programming guide is the right place to start. 
Also there are very good samples in Mac Dev Center and perhaps some iPhone examples are portable/useful as well (since CoreAudio in the iPhone is basically a sub-set of CoreAudio for the Mac)

2: You don't need to download anything else. If you have Xcode then just add CoreAudio.framework to your project and add `#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Nacho4d is right. You don't need to download anything. The CoreAudio.framework is included in XCode.

As for learning how to work with Core-Audio in general Apple's documentation may be painful to use if you are not a seasoned programmer. Only one book has been written on the subject so far: It's called [Core Audio (Rough Cuts)](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/audio/9780321636973) and it's written by Kevin Avila and Chris Adamson on Addison-Wesley Professional. It should help you with the basics.